# How to determine what type of SSD drive is supported for a Macbook?

Tags: macos, ssd

I am leaning towards getting a SSD for my MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2.53GHz, Mid 2009), since this is my first journey into SSD I was wondering if there was anything I needed to consider as far as drive specs when it comes to the mac. I am currently running Snow Leopard but will be upgrading to Lion shortly. As I understand Lion added Trim support, but I could not find a list of drives it supports Trim with.

- So does Lion support Trim on all SSD?
- Are there any other things I need to check to make sure the SSD I
  purchase is compatible?

Comment: I'm not so sure (It's Snow Leopard-era info.) but I thought that only Apple-branded SSDs were 'supported'.

Comment: @JFW I have heard that also, but have also heard the opposite. So I am not sure what to believe, and was just hoping to get some clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jfw is right, until now apple only supports their official SSD. While there are some ways to open SSD trim support on 3rd party SSD, when I used these solutions I encountered some weird problems.

Besides the trim support problem, some capability problems can be solved by updating SSD's firmware.

I currently use an Intel 320 300g SSD and installed lion without trim support, it has been working wonderfully.

Before I bought the Intel SSD, I had considered OWC's products and I think their products are good on capability, however since I am live outside of the United States I didn't choose it.

Comment: Thanks for the information and especially you own experiences on the matter. Gives me some things to think about.

Comment: You can look into [this thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=880594) on Mac Rumors forum. But in my opinion, without SATA-3 support on your Mid 2009 Macbook Pro, OWC still a better option.

Comment: Big thanks to @jschoen for correcting grammar errors in my answer and very sorry for my poor English.

Comment: No problem @AntiGameZ, don't worry about the poor English, it is my first (and only language) and my grammar is still horrible!

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be using a Samsung 830 (I believe Anandtech recommends it too). I'm having [some issues](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53936/freezes-on-macbook-w-lion-with-intel-330-ssd) with the Intel 330, so I'd recommend staying away from it.

Comment: Can you add some details on why you recommend this model?

Comment: In the [AnandTech review](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4863/the-samsung-ssd-830-review): "It's also worth pointing out that Samsung SSDs are also one of the two options Apple rebrands and delivers in its Mac lineup".

Although it does not refer to this particular model, I have the feeling that the ones used by Apple are very similar.